# I Can't get my quiz to pop up only once per item

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I am trying to create a 3D cave exploration mini game for Android tablets.
Throughout the cave, there will be items that when the player touches them, they will get Destroyed On Collision at which point a window will pop up with a multiple choice quiz mini game.

When the player object picks up the first item and the quiz pops up, it forces me to complete the whole quiz whereas I want the questions to be one or two per item.

Below are my three scripts that control the Quiz.

**QnA.cs**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class QnA
{
    public string Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectAnswers;
}
```

**QuizManager.cs**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class QuizManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<QnA> QnA;
    public GameObject[] options;
    public int CurrentQuestion;

    public GameObject QuizPanel;
    public GameObject GoPanel; //Game Over Panel

    public Text QuestionTxt;
    public Text ScoreText;

    int totalQuestions = 0;
    public int score;

    private void Start()
    {
        totalQuestions = QnA.Count; //Sets the total number of questions to the count of inserted questions.
        GoPanel.SetActive(false); //Deactivates the Game Over Panel
        GenerateQuestions();
    }

    //What to do if the questions are over.
    void GameOver()
    {
        QuizPanel.SetActive(false);
        GoPanel.SetActive(true);
        ScoreText.text = score + "/" + totalQuestions;
    }

    //Method attached to the button in the GameOverPanel to close the popup.
    public void CloseWindow()
    {
        GoPanel.SetActive(false);
    }

    //What to do if the answer is correct.
    public void correct()
    {
        score += 1;
        QnA.RemoveAt(CurrentQuestion);
        GenerateQuestions();
    }

    //What to do if the answer is wrong.
    public void wrong()
    {
        QnA.RemoveAt(CurrentQuestion);
        GenerateQuestions();
    }

    //Set the answer to the current question.
    void SetAnswers()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
        {
            options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = false;
            options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = QnA[CurrentQuestion].Answers[i];

            if (QnA[CurrentQuestion].CorrectAnswers == i+1)
            {
                options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = true;
            }
        }
    }

    void GenerateQuestions()
    {
        if (QnA.Count > 0)
        {
            CurrentQuestion = Random.Range(0, QnA.Count);

            QuestionTxt.text = QnA[CurrentQuestion].Question;
            SetAnswers();
        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("Out of Questions");
            GameOver();
        }
    }
}
```

**AnswerScript.cs** is the script that I have assigned the the multiple choice buttons in order to display if the answer is correct or wrong.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool isCorrect = false;
    public QuizManager quizManager;

    public void Answer()
    {
        if (isCorrect)
        {
            Debug.Log("Correct!");
            quizManager.correct();
        }else
        {
            Debug.Log("Wrong");
            quizManager.wrong();
        }
    }
}
```

I know that there is something that I have to add or change in the QuizManager to achieve what I want to do, but I have no idea.

Comment: Could you tell me the value of `QnA.Count;` for now I cannot see it anywhere in your code?

Comment: @che10 QnA is the list in which the questions that I have typed in Unity are saved.
In `Start()` I use the count of that list to set the total number of questions.
And then in `GenerateQuestions()` I again use the `QnA.Count` in an IF statement to say that if the Count is bigger than zero (if there are more than zero questions) then set the Current question as a random one from the QnA List.
That's how I structured it in my head and how I understand it, but I might be totally wrong and it might have no value at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I would adapt `quizmanager` to take an overview role, and implement a new class (e.g. `quizinstance`) that will display the questions and pass answers back to `quizmanager`. This way you can have `quizmanager` store all your questions and the players answers, and `quizinstance` pull `x` questions from the list when it gets created (when your collectable object gets destroyed).

Now when the player has answered as many questions as you want them to (`x`), `quizinstance` can be closed and the questions and answers associated with this `quizinstance` instance can be preserved in `quizmanager`.

Here is a rough attempt to explain what I mean. I haven't tested any of this code, but I hope it will give you a rough enough idea that you can fix any of the bugs it produces.

```
public static class QuizManager
{
    public static List<QnA> Questions = new();
    private static List<QnA> ServedQuestions = new();
    public static int Score;
    public static List<QnA> ServeQuestions()
    {
        return Questions.Where(q => 
!ServedQuestions.Contains(q)).Take(Mathf.Min(2, (Questions.Count - 
ServedQuestions.Count))).ToList();
    //this takes 2 questions in the event that there are atleast 2 un-asked questions left, the difference between total questions and asked questions otherwise
    //IMPORTANT: if more than one QuizInstance is going to exist at once, you'll need to modify this code to add the questions this function returns to 
    //ServedQuestions now, rather than in StoreResult. If you don't, it's possible that the same question gets picked more than once.
}

public static void StoreResult(QnA answeredQuestion)
{
    ServedQuestions.Add(answeredQuestion);
    //QuizInstance will call this function after a question has been answered. It stores our QnA
}

}

[System.Serializable]
public class QnA
{
    public string Question;
    public string[] Answers;
    public int CorrectAnswers;
}

public class QuizInstance : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<QnA> QnA;
    public GameObject[] options;
    public int CurrentQuestion;

    public GameObject QuizPanel;
    public GameObject GoPanel; //Game Over Panel

    public Text QuestionTxt;
    public Text ScoreText;

    int totalQuestions = 0;

    private void Start()
    {
        QnA.AddRange(QuizManager.ServeQuestions()); //Pull a list of 
    //questions for this QuizInstance to ask
    totalQuestions = QnA.Count; //Sets the total number of questions 
//to the count of inserted questions.
    //GoPanel.SetActive(false); //Don't deactivate the panel here, 
//have the panel deactivated in the editor and activate it when needed.
    GenerateQuestions();
}

//What to do if the questions are over.
void GameOver()
{
    QuizPanel.SetActive(false);
    GoPanel.SetActive(true);
    ScoreText.text = QuizManager.Score + "/" + totalQuestions;
}

//Method attached to the button in the GameOverPanel to close the popup.
public void CloseWindow()
{
    GoPanel.SetActive(false);
}

//What to do if the answer is correct.
public void correct()
{
    QuizManager.Score += 1;
    QuizManager.StoreResult(QnA[CurrentQuestion]);
}

//What to do if the answer is wrong.
public void wrong()
{
    QuizManager.StoreResult(QnA[CurrentQuestion]);
}

//Set the answer to the current question.
void SetAnswers()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < options.Length; i++)
    {
        options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = false;
        options[i].transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Text>().text = QnA[CurrentQuestion].Answers[i];

        if (QnA[CurrentQuestion].CorrectAnswers == i + 1)
        {
            options[i].GetComponent<AnswerScript>().isCorrect = true;
        }
    }
}

void GenerateQuestions()
{
    if (QnA.Count > 0)
    {
        CurrentQuestion = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, QnA.Count);

        QuestionTxt.text = QnA[CurrentQuestion].Question;
        SetAnswers();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Out of Questions");
        GameOver();
    }
}
}

public class AnswerScript : MonoBehaviour
{
public bool isCorrect = false;
public QuizInstance quizInstance;

public void Answer()
{
    if (isCorrect)
    {
        Debug.Log("Correct!");
        quizInstance.correct();
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Wrong");
        quizInstance.wrong();
    }
}`
```

Comment: Hello @Dan, thanks for the response.   I think I understand what you said, but I can't achieve it.   What I understand from your statement is that I should create a new class so that it will be used instead of the quizmanager as a local class/script for each object, but the quizmanager will stay as a "master" class/script that will hold all the information (list of questions & answers). 
  I'm new to the programming world and what I've achieved/written so far has been after reading. video watching and stack overflow searching.  
Would you mind demonstrating if it isn't too much of a bother?

Comment: I'll see if I can draft it up for you tonight @ChristosFotos. Happy to hop on discord or something similar and talk you through what I've done if you're still struggling after that.

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I decided to approach the project with Scriptable Objects (which have taken me down a whole other road) but I appreciate the response and the time you took. I have but one question, although I understand the Linq line in the `ServeQuestions()` method, I get an error saying that "Tuple must contain at least two elements" and that "A new expression requires (), [] or {} after type" when you declare the `new()` Questions & ServedQuestions Lists. But even if I modify those 2 lines to not get an error the method returns null. So I guess I'm modifying it wrong.

Comment: the `new()` initializer has only just been released and `Unity` hasn't actually implemented it yet, that's my mistake - sorry! Serves me right for not checking my code. Initialize `Questions` and `ServedQuestions` with `= new List<QnA>();`. I'll have to get back to you on the `Tuple` error, I don't have `Unity` installed on my work PC so can't troubleshoot for you.

Comment: Don't worry about it. Thanks once again for the response. Being able to see the logistics was interesting and I read about a lot of new things.